# How to hit a specific REST Url based on maven profile?

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey-client

I have the following two REST Urls in my application.properties.

I would like to fetch one but not both based on dynamic parameter but not sure how. I tried using maven profile but not sure how to read the maven profile in Java code and get the url's based on that.

Please guide.

**application.properties**

```
rest.uri=http://localhost:8080/hello
mock.rest.uri=http://localhost:9999/hello
```

**RestClient.java**

```
public class HelloWorldClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Client client = Client.create();

            //getRestUrl() METHOD CALL NEEDS TO BE DYNAMIC 
            //EITHER MOCK URL OR ACTUAL REST URL SHOULD BE FETCHED HERE 
            // NOT SURE HOW ???????
            WebResource webResource = client.resource(getRestUrl());

            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("text/plain").get(ClientResponse.class);
            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
            }
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("\nOutput from Server.... " + output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getRestUrl() throws IOException {
        Properties prop = GenericUtils.loadProperties("application.properties");
        String restUri = prop.getProperty("rest.uri");
        String mockRestUri = prop.getProperty("mock.rest.uri");
        System.out.println("restUri = " + restUri);
        System.out.println("mockRestUri = " + mockRestUri);
        return mockRestUri;
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>rest-server</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>mock-rest-server</id>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: You could have multiple versions of your `application.properties` file. Depending on the Maven profile, pack the right one in your application.

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation or example ?

Comment: Why do you even need to do this? Place a configuration file outside the JAR containing this URL, and then the code would simply read whatever is in that file. You can then edit that file at any time, and restart your app, no weird custom packaging / profiles involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the solution provided by Jose and Fetta above I altered the program and  hereby aggregating both the solutions into this post and posting it here.

**application.properties**

```
rest.uri=${rest.uri}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/application.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>rest-server</id>
        <properties>
            <rest.uri>http://localhost:8080/hello</rest.uri>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>mock-rest-server</id>
        <properties>
            <rest.uri>http://localhost:9999/hello</rest.uri>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**HelloWorldClient.java**

```
public class HelloWorldClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client.resource(getRestUrl());
            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("text/plain").get(ClientResponse.class);
            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
            }
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("\nOutput from Server.... " + output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getRestUrl() throws IOException {
        Properties prop = GenericUtils.loadProperties("application.properties");
        String restUri = prop.getProperty("rest.uri");
        System.out.println("restUri = " + restUri);
        return restUri;
    }

}
```

**Compile the class using profiles**

```
mvn clean install -Prest-server
mvn clean install -Pmock-rest-server
```

**Run the main method**

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.HelloWorldClient"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a single property and depending on the maven profile that is executed it will be filled with one value or another.

For example:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>rest-server</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
          <rest.uri>ttp://localhost:8080/hello</rest.uri>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>mock-rest-server</id>
        <properties>
          <rest.uri>http://localhost:9999/hello</rest.uri>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now, **application.properties** file:

```
rest.uri=${rest.uri}
```

The filtering plugin of maven will perform the substitution of the value according to the profile that is executed.

From the java code you can always read the same property because it will have the value mock or real depending on the maven profile that has been executed

Answer (score 1):

You can use Maven Resources Plugin for filtering resources. It's usage is described here:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Then you can define profile-specific properties in your profiles. After that, during build your .properties file will be filtered during build and your application can use it. The .properties value will be different depending on which profile was activated during build.

It's all described in the link.